# Complexity of Lua stack operations (Lua C API)

Tags: c, lua

In the Lua C API, it offers couple stack operation functions as mentioned in [Lua's document](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.2.3.html)

```
int   lua_gettop (lua_State *L);
void  lua_settop (lua_State *L, int index);
void  lua_pushvalue (lua_State *L, int index);
void  lua_remove (lua_State *L, int index);
void  lua_insert (lua_State *L, int index);
void  lua_replace (lua_State *L, int index);
```

My first question is, what is the complexity of these function?  Is it O(1) or O(|index|)?  I checked the [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf) and it seems Lua has two different implementations of stack (stack based and register based).

More specifically, if I would like to read and pop the top three elements from the lua stack, I can think of the following two implementations, can I know which one is more performant / suggested way?

Solution 1 -- read and pop for each value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  values[i] = lua_tostring(lua_state, -1);
  ...
  lua_pop(lua_state, 1);
}
```

Solution 2 -- read all and then pop all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  values[i] = lua_tostring(lua_state, -1 - i);
}
...
lua_pop(lua_state, 3);
```

Comment: Why not look at the source code?

Comment: But different versions might have different implementations?  Just want to know the whether one is always preferred than the other.

Comment: A suggestion.. the pointer returned from `lua_tostring` is not guaranteed to be valid after popping it from the stack. See [lua_tolstring](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_tolstring) in the manual. Make a copy if you need to keep a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lua 5.3 defines](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lua.h.html) `lua_pop` as

```
#define lua_pop(L,n)            lua_settop(L, -(n)-1)
```

and `lua_settop` can be seen [here](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lapi.c.html); it will fill the stack slots with `nil` so the values can be gc'd. So it's O(1) with arg `1`.

You can read each value in O(1), and the pop of N values is O(N).

So, your two approaches should be roughly equivalent.

Re: reading values in O(1), the function [index2addr](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lapi.c.html#index2addr) is what translates a stack offset to an address.

Comment: This answer seems to make no sense whatsoever. The question is whether accessing element -3 is slower than accessing element -1. The question isn't even about `lua_pop`! And even if it was, your answer doesn't tell us anything about the speed of `lua_pop`.

Comment: @immibis, sorry, I posted before completing the response. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Still, the question is not asking about the performance of `lua_pop`, but about the performance of other functions that access the stack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  About "You can read each value in O(1)", do you happen to have a reference to justify this part?

Comment: Right, but the `lua_pop` is actually the dominant operation at O(N).

Comment: @keelar, see my addendum on `index2addr`